# Dynamics CRM Online - how to get rid of 'First Things First' intro screen

Tags: crm

Since Dynamics CRM Online was upgrade to the new 2013 version, this 'First Things First' screen pops up pretty constantly:

[image: intro screen]

Ticking 'don't show me this again' makes it go away for a bit, but seems to be controlled via cookies, so if you clear your cookies or history the intro screen comes back.

Is there some way to turn this off in CRM Online?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks like it requires registry changes...

http://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/117497.aspx